# Code for sorting table using mysql database information

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code for sorting my tables information based on status.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM affiliate_tasks WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'";

if( isset($_POST['sort-selection'] && $_POST['sort-selection'] != 'all' ) ) 
{
   $query .= " AND status = '". $_POST['sort-selection']."';" ;
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

When I run the web page it gives me this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ',' or ')' in /home/content/38/10473938/html/website/panda/affiliates/task.php on line 60
```

Line 60 is as follows:

```
if( isset($_POST['sort-selection'] && $_POST['sort-selection'] != 'all' ) ) {
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with the code any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You misplaced the closing `)` of `isset`.

Comment: Why the -1 ? It is a legitimate question

Comment: That doesn't automatically mean it's a *good* question.

Comment: no but legitimate is fine! back off!

Comment: The poster does may a good point though.  Constructive criticism when downvoting is usually helpful and is encouraged.

Comment: Constructive criticism: A syntax error is a hyper-localized problem no-one else is ever going to benefit from but you right now in this second. But your question *will* turn up in search results, with a title which may even attract interest in completely unrelated topics, spamming search results and making it just a little harder to find useful questions and answers other people can benefit from. Therefore: downvote, to keep the system clean. For such super tiny problems, consider asking in the chat.

Comment: You could have just said that! I didn't even know there was other ways to ask rather than making a question. Where is this chat?

Comment: Look in the top navigation bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks as though you've got the closing brackets in the wrong place on that line..

```
if( isset($_POST['sort-selection'] && $_POST['sort-selection'] != 'all' ) ) {
```

should be

```
if( isset($_POST['sort-selection']) && $_POST['sort-selection'] != 'all' ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your closing bracket

```
if( isset($_POST['sort-selection']) && $_POST['sort-selection'] != 'all' ) 
                                //^this one was missed and added at the end
```